# Set up listeners when a model is created or disposed for @monaco-editor/react

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

I have a web application containing a Monaco Editor. Previously, I used [react-monaco-editor](https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor), now for some reasons, I'm thinking of switching to [@monaco-editor/react](https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react).

With react-monaco-editor, I was able to code a `DiagnosticsAdapter` class to provide real-time error checking and suggestions in a code editor. When a user types code into the editor, the adapter will validate the code and provide feedback on any issues it finds.

Now, with @monaco-editor/react, the `DiagnosticsAdapter` does not work anymore: code in `onModelAdd` and code in `onModelRemoved` is never executed.

[image]

Does anyone know how to set up these listeners for @monaco-editor/react and make `DiagnosticsAdapter` work?

Here is CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-voice-5rz8z2?file=/src/App.js:0-542

Here is `language-feature.ts`:

```
import * as monaco from "monaco-editor";

export class DiagnosticsAdapter {
  private _disposables: monaco.IDisposable[] = [];
  private _listener = Object.create(null);

  constructor() {
    console.log("herehere in constructor");

    const onModelAdd = (model: monaco.editor.IModel): void => {
      console.log("herehere onModelAdd");

      let handle;
      const changeSubscription = model.onDidChangeContent(() => {
        clearTimeout(handle);
        handle = setTimeout(() => console.log("call validation"), 500);
      });

      this._listener[model.uri.toString()] = {
        dispose() {
          changeSubscription.dispose();
          clearTimeout(handle);
        }
      };

      console.log("call vailidation");
    };

    const onModelRemoved = (model: monaco.editor.IModel): void => {
      console.log("herehere onModelRemoved");
      monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(model, "abc", []);
      const key = model.uri.toString();
      if (this._listener[key]) {
        this._listener[key].dispose();
        delete this._listener[key];
      }
    };

    console.log("herehere 5");
    this._disposables.push(monaco.editor.onDidCreateModel(onModelAdd));
    console.log("herehere 6");
    this._disposables.push(monaco.editor.onWillDisposeModel(onModelRemoved));
    console.log("herehere 7");
    this._disposables.push(
      monaco.editor.onDidChangeModelLanguage((event) => {
        console.log("herehere 8");
        onModelRemoved(event.model);
        console.log("herehere 9");
        onModelAdd(event.model);
      })
    );

    console.log("herehere 10");
    this._disposables.push({
      dispose() {
        for (const model of monaco.editor.getModels()) {
          onModelRemoved(model);
        }
      }
    });

    console.log("herehere 11");
    monaco.editor.getModels().forEach(onModelAdd);
  }

  public dispose(): void {
    this._disposables.forEach((d) => d && d.dispose());
    this._disposables = [];
  }
}
```

Here is `App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react";
import { DiagnosticsAdapter } from "./language-feature";

function App() {
  function handleEditorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
    monaco.languages.register({ id: "mySpecialLanguage" });

    let x = new DiagnosticsAdapter();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Editor
        height="90vh"
        defaultLanguage="mySpecialLanguage"
        defaultValue="// some comment"
        onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manipulate models with `@monaco-editor/react`, you should use the `handleEditorDidMount` method to access the editor instance and the editor object itself, which has the methods you need for handling models.

**Here's an example**:

```
function App() {
  function handleEditorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
    monaco.languages.register({ id: "mySpecialLanguage" });

    // Initialize the DiagnosticAdapter here.
    let diagnosticAdapter = new DiagnosticsAdapter(editor, monaco);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Editor
        height="90vh"
        defaultLanguage="mySpecialLanguage"
        defaultValue="// some comment"
        onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Here's an updated DiagnosticsAdapter class**:

```
import * as monaco from "monaco-editor";

export class DiagnosticsAdapter {
  private _disposables: monaco.IDisposable[] = [];
  private _listener = Object.create(null);
  private _editor: monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor;
  private _monaco: typeof monaco;

  constructor(editor: monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor, monaco: typeof monaco) {
    this._editor = editor;
    this._monaco = monaco;

    console.log("herehere in constructor");

    const onModelAdd = (model: monaco.editor.IModel): void => {
      console.log("herehere onModelAdd");

      let handle;
      const changeSubscription = model.onDidChangeContent(() => {
        clearTimeout(handle);
        handle = setTimeout(() => console.log("call validation"), 500);
      });

      this._listener[model.uri.toString()] = {
        dispose() {
          changeSubscription.dispose();
          clearTimeout(handle);
        }
      };

      console.log("call vailidation");
    };

    const onModelRemoved = (model: monaco.editor.IModel): void => {
      console.log("herehere onModelRemoved");
      this._monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(model, "abc", []);
      const key = model.uri.toString();
      if (this._listener[key]) {
        this._listener[key].dispose();
        delete this._listener[key];
      }
    };

    // Get the model for the current editor instance.
    let model = this._editor.getModel();

    if (model) {
      onModelAdd(model);
    }

    console.log("herehere 5");
    this._disposables.push(model.onWillDispose(() => onModelRemoved(model)));
    console.log("herehere 6");
    this._disposables.push(
      this._editor.onDidChangeModel((event) => {
        console.log("herehere 8");
        onModelRemoved(event.oldModel);
        console.log("herehere 9");
        onModelAdd(event.newModel);
      })
    );

    console.log("herehere 10");
    this._disposables.push({
      dispose() {
        onModelRemoved(model);
      }
    });

    console.log("herehere 11");
  }

  public dispose(): void {
    this._disposables.forEach((d) => d && d.dispose());
    this._disposables = [];
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Note that `editor.onDidChangeModel` only fires when the model associated with the editor changes, not when any model in the system changes.

Comment: Thank you. Here is CodeSandbox of your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-bhabha-p8lk9l